# Get JSON value from column

Tags: json, bash, unix, awk, jq

I have a bunch of two column logs which are separated by tabs. The second column is valid JSON:

```
2019-02-28T19:43:48.585Z        {"id": 1234, "catId": 42, "img": "other.jpg"}
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        {"id": 4321, "catId": 999, "img": "my.jpg"}
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        {"id": 1234, "catId": 42, "img": "new.jpg"}
2019-02-28T19:46:48.585Z        {"id": 1234, "catId": 765, "img": "cat.jpg"}
```

My aim to to retain the timestamp column, and print the `catId` property:

```
2019-02-28T19:43:48.585Z        42
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        999
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        42
2019-02-28T19:46:48.585Z        765
```

My attempt so far has been to plug `jq` with `awk`, but I am struggling with the `system` command.

```sh
awk -F '\t' '{printf "\n %s \t %s \n", $1, system("jq .catId <<< " $2)}' file
```

Any help in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: `awk -F ' *|\t*|,' '{print $1,$6}' file`?

Comment: `tr '\t' ' ' | cut -d' ' -f1,5` - will work if you are lucky enough, so the fields inside the json have no spaces in them.

Comment: Awk's `system()` should almost never be used -- using it runs serious security risks. `<<<"$2"` in shell is safe because it'll never interpret the content in `$2` as code, but if you had a `"img": "$(rm -rf ~).jpg"` in your input document, you'd have an *extremely* bad day with awk's `system()` substituting in that same value, because awk doesn't have any way to tell the shell it invokes with `system()` which characters are eligible to be syntax and which are literal data.

Comment: ...one might *think* that putting literal quotes into the content added by awk would avoid this risk, but it doesn't, because the literal content can contain literal quotes as well: Consider a file named `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.jpg`; the left one expands in double quotes, the right one expands in single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the files are tab delimited, you could read the file in raw, split on the tabs, parse and extract the json, then rejoin on tabs.

```
$ jq -Rr 'split("\t") | .[1] |= fromjson.catId | join("\t")' input.log
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the `|=` does?

Comment: @test: Assignments `=` simply takes the value on the RHS and updates the field on the LHS. The context for that value is unchanged, meaning the "input" for the value is the same input on the LHS. Using `|=` changes the context so that the "input" for the value is the value of the LHS.

Comment: @Jeff, Is it possible to add another array item? pseudo code: `.[1] |= fromjson.catId .[2] = fromjson.another'`

Comment: @test: You should be able to do: `... | . += [$yourItem] | ...`. I personally prefer: `... | [.[], $yourItem] | ...`

Comment: @Jeff. can't seem to get this working. Works with static string like `... | [.[], "foo"] | ...` but not with dynamic `... |  [.[], fromjson.id] | ...`

Comment: @test: You'll have to be aware of what the current context is. In your example, it's the array of items that's the current "input" so using `fromjson` on that array would be an error. it only works in the answer above because we changed the context to be the second item in the array (`.[1] |= ...`), if you wanted to add multiple values from that one object, you'll want to do it within that update-assignment. e.g., `... | .[1:] |= (.[0] | fromjson | [.catId, .img]) | ...` (note the change in the LHS)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{sub(/,/,"",$5);print $1"\t"$5}' file

2019-02-28T19:43:48.585Z    42
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z    999
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z    42
2019-02-28T19:46:48.585Z    765
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding why your code didn't work as the previous answers are better. In your case `$2` was being interpreted as multiple arguments by `jq` as `$2` contains spaces.

So, in the below code `$2` is put within hex values single-quotes `\x27` and then double-quotes.
Also a little bit of formatting to keep the output in the same line.

`awk -F '\t' '{printf "%s\t", $1;system("jq .catId <<< \x27"$2"\x27")}' file`

Output:

```
2019-02-28T19:43:48.585Z        42
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        999
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        42
2019-02-28T19:46:48.585Z        765
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r timestamp json; do
    printf '%s\t%s\n' "$timestamp" "$(jq -r .catId <<<"$json")"
done < file
```

this will be much slower than the jq oneliner.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl

```
perl -lanE ' $x=$_=~s/(^.*catId":\s*)(\d+).*$/$2/gr; print "$F[0]\t$x" '
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat test.log
2019-02-28T19:43:48.585Z        {"id": 1234, "catId": 42, "img": "other.jpg"}
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        {"id": 4321, "catId": 999, "img": "my.jpg"}
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        {"id": 1234, "catId": 42, "img": "new.jpg"}
2019-02-28T19:46:48.585Z        {"id": 1234, "catId": 765, "img": "cat.jpg"}

$  perl -lanE ' $x=$_=~s/(^.*catId":\s*)(\d+).*$/$2/gr; print "$F[0]\t$x" ' test.log
2019-02-28T19:43:48.585Z        42
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        999
2019-02-28T19:44:48.585Z        42
2019-02-28T19:46:48.585Z        765

$
```